# How to convert nfa to dfa

Tags: dfa, nfa

￼[Question in note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxwAL.jpg)

[my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbPou.jpg)

I find a question in my note and when I try to convert the nfa to a dfa, i get a similar result but not exactly the same. what am i doing wrong? or is my answer also acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the name (or label) of state doesn't really matter. Your answer is exactly the same as that in your note.

After doing conversion, you can change the label i.e `q0q1` to `q1` and `q0q2` to `q2`. Or to whatever names you like.

The important thing of NFA/DFA is the structure. Start state, final state, and the transition.